# Equational identities of unordered $n$-tuples

Tags: set-theory, universal-algebra

I asked this question on math stack exchange, but I did not get an answer, so I am asking it here. This question combines both universal algebra and set theory. Let $V$ be a model of ZFC set theory, let $n$ be a positive integer, let $f_n$ be the $n$-ary unordered $n$-tuple operation, and consider the structure $(V;f_n)$. I want to know what a finite basis for the equational identities of that structure are. I conjecture that the "permutative" identities are sufficient. By a permutative $n$-ary operation, I mean an operation that remains the same under any permutation of its variables. So, to give two examples, a permutative binary operation is just a commutative binary operation, and a permutative ternary operation is one that satisfies the identities $f(x,y,z)=f(x,z,y)=f(y,x,z)=f(y,z,x)=f(z,x,y)=f(z,y,x)$. Is my conjecture true, or do we need further identities?

Comment: No (for $n\ge3$). Apart from permutations, you also need the identity $f(x,x,y,\vec z)=f(x,y,y,\vec z)$. Then it is easily seen to be complete.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That should probably be an answer.